# LibGDX: What is the harm in keeping 1 SpriteBatch for everything and not disposing it?

Tags: java, libgdx

I've been researching memory leaks, and I'm confused why `SpriteBatch.dispose()` is supposed to be called. I thought when you run `spriteBatch.begin()` and `spriteBatch.end()` that would be sufficient to prevent memory leaks and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `begin()` and `end()` are very different from the `dispose` method.

According to the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html),

You are right about the behavior of the `dispose` method.

> Releases all resources of this object.

`begin()` and `end()` are used to set the associated `Batch` for rendering, note that you can have multiple batches drawing. All draw calls on a batch must be done between the `begin` and the `end` methods. They have nothing to do with releasing memory, so that is why you need to do `dispose()` if you desire to do so.

Comment: I suppose I'll ask you the same thing I asked sorifiend: if I don't call dispose(), does the information from previous draws build up?

Comment: With all the good answers here, think your question is answered. But if you're still a bit unusre, just look at the code for the dispose() method of SpriteBatch. While begin() and end() are used over and over again for rendering, dispose() gets rid of the internals SpriteBatch uses for rendering (internals that need to be freed - Mesh and possibly a Shader), once you no longer need the SpriteBatch for rendering: @Override   public void dispose () {mesh.dispose(); if (ownsShader && shader != null) shader.dispose(); }

Answer (score 3):

You definitely **do not** want to dispose it every frame or after every `end`. It will not build up. Once you are finished using the batch, you want to dispose it (which is most likely when closing the application or changing `Screen`)

Answer (score 2):

`SpriteBatch.end()` Finishes off rendering. Enables depth writes, disables blending and texturing.

`SpriteBatch.dispose()` actually releases all resources of this object, and prevents memory leak.

So after using `SpriteBatch.end()` the item may be kept in memory depending on other aspects of your code, especially if you want to re-use it again later. So dispose should always be called when you are completly finished with the SpriteBatch, else there is no guarantee that the memory will be freed.

Comment: So if I don't call `dispose()`, does the information from previous draws build up?

Comment: If you reuse the same SpriteBatch over and over then it wont build up. But if you create a new one each time then it can build up.

Answer (score 1):

Disposable resources need to be disposed but where ?

1. If you're creating your `SpriteBatch` in `create()` method of `ApplicationListener` and using it all over the game on different screen, dispose them ApplicationListener's `dispose()` method.
2. Else if you're creating in Screen's `show()` method then dispose in Screen's `dispose()` method but dispose method not called by ApplicationListener or Framework, so you need to call dispose method by yourself so call dispose method from `hide()` method of Screen.

`begin()` and `end()` method is use to achieve the Purpose of `SpriteBatch`:

To batch multiple sprites into a single draw call in order to minimize the associated performance penalty of each draw call.